# Azure blob storage split blobs and store on Cloud file share

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, fileshare

I am uploading zip files to Azure Blob Storage which are relatively huge.

Now I need to go to those containers, get the blob reference and store that zip file into multiple zips on Cloud file share. I am not sure how to proceed with that.

```
var storageAccount = AzureUtility.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString();
            var container = AzureUtility.GetAzureCloudBlobContainerReference("fabcd");
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("sample-share");
            share.CreateIfNotExists();

            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Test.zip");
            var file = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("Test.zip").Exists();

if(file)
{
     //split and share
}
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you're trying to download a blob and then divide and upload it into multiple files.

There's two options here both of which are exposed through the .Net API. The blob API exposes both DownloadRangeTo* methods and DownloadTo* methods. The file API exposes UploadFrom* methods. If you know in advance the divisions you want to make you can download the range and then upload it to the file. Otherwise you can download the entire blob, divide it client side, and then upload the divisions.